# How to run shell commands in a C program

Tags: c, cmd

I am really new to advanced programming (at least this is advanced for me)

I want to learn how to run shell commands through C program on windows

I did search for it and I know it has got something to do with `system()` and `exec()` but I didn't get a definite answer.

To begin with,i would like to execute cd command and also md command

So if someone can break this down to really basic level,it will be much appreciated. Thank you

P.S. I succeeded in doing so and I know now one shouldn't run system commands through C but this was just an assignment.Thank you

Comment: You want to run a DOS command on unix? sorry your tags are very confusing! You must be specific too, do you want to handle the output of the program?

Comment: Example usage: `system("dir");`

Comment: No not on Unix sorry. Just plain C program on windows to run dos commands like say dir,del,creating a file and everything else
I am just learning now so don't really have to do much with the output
Running those commands is all I need as of now

Comment: To clear up your terminology, DOS = (Disk Operating System), an old operating system that is mostly gone by now. You are asking how to run shell commands on the Windows shell (Command Prompt or "cmd.exe").

Comment: oh,thank you for that...I am really starting from scratch here

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to run "DOS commands" directly from a C program.  Instead, you should consider using the [tag:Win32] API to accomplish the tasks you want.  If all you really want to do is automate the commands, consider using a [batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file).

Comment: Also, if all you're doing is looking to delete files or list directories, there are functions that can achieve that in C without running external programs. If that's what you want, edit your question to reflect it, otherwise let us know that you specifically want to run these commands.

Comment: Okay i think I should change my question...I was just looking for a resource to learn all this...I have absolutely no prior knowledge about any of this..sorry

Comment: does DOS still exist on some computers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a short program that runs `dir` from inside a C program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("dir");
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, whatever command you pass as a string inside the parameter for `system()` is run using the shell on your system. In your case, since you are working on Windows, it is equivalent to running the string inside your command prompt. This is equivalent to the "DOS Commands" you talk about. However, these are actually shell commands.

**Note:** In general, you do NOT want to be running `system()` since there are almost always a better way of doing things. Also, if your code is just basically what is above, then you're better off writing a batch file (i.e. a `.bat` file).

Comment: Specially because using `system()` means you rely on a given program being installed in the particular system, which might be not.